# Tensorboard is not showing any information in profile tab

Tags: tensorboard

I am trying to explore model tuning through tensorboard profiling tab and was trying to generate files through tensorboard call back as shared below.

```py
    log_dir="logs/profile/" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")

    tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir,
    histogram_freq=1, profile_batch = 3)
    model.fit(train_data,
             steps_per_epoch=20,
             epochs=10, 
             callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
```

and it has generated following files in my colab. Have then downloaded these files into my local PC to view in tensorboard but nothing is getting displayed in Profile tab. All the other tab showing information.

> logs/profile/ logs/profile/20190907-130136/
>   logs/profile/20190907-130136/train/
>   logs/profile/20190907-130136/train/events.out.tfevents.1567861315.340ae5d21d3b.profile-empty
>   logs/profile/20190907-130136/train/events.out.tfevents.1567861301.340ae5d21d3b.119.129998.v2
>   logs/profile/20190907-130136/train/plugins/
>   logs/profile/20190907-130136/train/plugins/profile/
>   logs/profile/20190907-130136/train/plugins/profile/2019-09-07_13-01-55/
>   logs/profile/20190907-130136/train/plugins/profile/2019-09-07_13-01-55/local.trace

The script is located in https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/docs/r2/tensorboard_profiling_keras.ipynb

Wanted to attach the files but there is no option to attach he files here...Can anyone please help why profile info from this script is not getting displayed into local PC tensorboard profile tab?

Comment: I did tensorboard inspect and information seems to be there in files..

Comment: You need to use a newer version of Tensorboard. TensorBoard 2.0.0 is working for me, but TensorBoard 1.9.0 has the same problem as yours.

Comment: Is there a solution for this yet? I have the exact same problem, using tensorflow 2.0.1 and opening TensorBoard in Chrome.
The other tabs show information fine, but the profile tab stays empty.

Comment: @Astrid I downgraded my tensorflow plugin profile and tensorboard to get the profile tab. But profile is still unable to capture data

Answer (score 7):

Apparently you need to use Chrome to view the profile information: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/2874

Answer (score 0):

I think you must install tensorboard plugin profile.

[using this link to guid.](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/docs/tensorboard_profiling_keras.ipynb#scrollTo=dFWOMyaHkUX5)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).