# How do I get the Tensorflow Profiler working in Tensorflow 2.5 with 'tensorflow-macos' and 'tensorflow-metal'

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, profiler

I am running Big Sur OS-X 11.5, Tensorflow 2.5 with Python 3.8.

When I try to display the profiler tab I got this error:

W0726 08:25:03.846074 123145487446016 application.py:556] path /data/index.js not found, sending 404

```
% pip list
Package                    Version
-------------------------- -------------------
absl-py                    0.12.0
anyio                      3.2.1
appnope                    0.1.2
argon2-cffi                20.1.0
astunparse                 1.6.3
async-generator            1.10
attrs                      21.2.0
Babel                      2.9.1
backcall                   0.2.0
bleach                     3.3.1
cachetools                 4.2.2
certifi                    2021.5.30
cffi                       1.14.6
charset-normalizer         2.0.1
cycler                     0.10.0
Cython                     0.29.24
debugpy                    1.3.0
decorator                  5.0.9
defusedxml                 0.7.1
dill                       0.3.4
dotmap                     1.3.23
entrypoints                0.3
flatbuffers                1.12
future                     0.18.2
gast                       0.4.0
gensim                     4.0.1
google-auth                1.32.1
google-auth-oauthlib       0.4.4
google-pasta               0.2.0
googleapis-common-protos   1.53.0
grpcio                     1.34.1
gviz-api                   1.9.0
h5py                       3.1.0
idna                       3.2
importlib-resources        5.2.0
ipykernel                  6.0.1
ipython                    7.25.0
ipython-genutils           0.2.0
ipywidgets                 7.6.3
jedi                       0.18.0
Jinja2                     3.0.1
json5                      0.9.6
jsonschema                 3.2.0
jupyter-client             6.1.12
jupyter-core               4.7.1
jupyter-server             1.9.0
jupyterlab                 3.0.16
jupyterlab-pygments        0.1.2
jupyterlab-server          2.6.1
jupyterlab-widgets         1.0.0
keras-nightly              2.5.0.dev2021032900
Keras-Preprocessing        1.1.2
kiwisolver                 1.3.1
Markdown                   3.3.4
MarkupSafe                 2.0.1
matplotlib                 3.4.2
matplotlib-inline          0.1.2
mistune                    0.8.4
nbclassic                  0.3.1
nbclient                   0.5.3
nbconvert                  6.1.0
nbformat                   5.1.3
nest-asyncio               1.5.1
notebook                   6.4.0
numpy                      1.19.5
oauthlib                   3.1.1
opt-einsum                 3.3.0
packaging                  21.0
pandas                     1.3.0
pandocfilters              1.4.3
parso                      0.8.2
pexpect                    4.8.0
pickleshare                0.7.5
Pillow                     8.3.1
pip                        21.1.3
prometheus-client          0.11.0
promise                    2.3
prompt-toolkit             3.0.19
protobuf                   3.17.3
ptyprocess                 0.7.0
pyasn1                     0.4.8
pyasn1-modules             0.2.8
pybind11                   2.6.2
pycparser                  2.20
Pygments                   2.9.0
pyparsing                  2.4.7
pyrsistent                 0.18.0
python-dateutil            2.8.2
pytz                       2021.1
pyzmq                      22.1.0
requests                   2.26.0
requests-oauthlib          1.3.0
requests-unixsocket        0.2.0
rsa                        4.7.2
scipy                      1.7.0
Send2Trash                 1.7.1
setuptools                 41.2.0
six                        1.15.0
smart-open                 5.1.0
sniffio                    1.2.0
tensorboard                2.5.0
tensorboard-data-server    0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-profile 2.4.0
tensorboard-plugin-wit     1.8.0
tensorflow-datasets        4.3.0
tensorflow-estimator       2.5.0
tensorflow-hub             0.12.0
tensorflow-macos           2.5.0
tensorflow-metadata        1.1.0
tensorflow-metal           0.1.1
termcolor                  1.1.0
terminado                  0.10.1
testpath                   0.5.0
tornado                    6.1
tqdm                       4.61.2
traitlets                  5.0.5
typing-extensions          3.7.4.3
urllib3                    1.26.6
wcwidth                    0.2.5
webencodings               0.5.1
websocket-client           1.1.0
Werkzeug                   2.0.1
wheel                      0.36.2
widgetsnbextension         3.5.1
wrapt                      1.12.1
zipp                       3.5.0
```

I followed the steps outlined (below) to test the Tensorbord profiler:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/tensorboard_profiling_keras

The profile tab is empty the other tabs are fine.

[image]

[image]

Output from training:

```
# Create a TensorBoard callback
logs = "logs/" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")

tboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir = logs,
                                                 histogram_freq = 1,
                                                 profile_batch = '500,520')

model.fit(ds_train,
          epochs=2,
          validation_data=ds_test,
          callbacks = [tboard_callback])

2021-07-26 08:24:10.046068: I tensorflow/core/profiler/lib/profiler_session.cc:126] Profiler session initializing.
2021-07-26 08:24:10.046080: I tensorflow/core/profiler/lib/profiler_session.cc:141] Profiler session started.
2021-07-26 08:24:10.046398: I tensorflow/core/profiler/lib/profiler_session.cc:159] Profiler session tear down.
2021-07-26 08:24:10.155591: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:176] None of the MLIR Optimization Passes are enabled (registered 2)
Epoch 1/2
2021-07-26 08:24:10.350671: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/custom_graph_optimizer_registry.cc:112] Plugin optimizer for device_type GPU is enabled.
467/469 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3578 - accuracy: 0.9012
2021-07-26 08:24:18.130834: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/custom_graph_optimizer_registry.cc:112] Plugin optimizer for device_type GPU is enabled.
469/469 [==============================] - 9s 11ms/step - loss: 0.3571 - accuracy: 0.9014 - val_loss: 0.1861 - val_accuracy: 0.9457
Epoch 2/2
 49/469 [==>...........................] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.1939 - accuracy: 0.9428
2021-07-26 08:24:19.001183: I tensorflow/core/profiler/lib/profiler_session.cc:126] Profiler session initializing.
2021-07-26 08:24:19.001196: I tensorflow/core/profiler/lib/profiler_session.cc:141] Profiler session started.
2021-07-26 08:24:19.182713: I tensorflow/core/profiler/lib/profiler_session.cc:66] Profiler session collecting data.
 58/469 [==>...........................] - ETA: 5s - loss: 0.1920 - accuracy: 0.9436
2021-07-26 08:24:19.273235: I tensorflow/core/profiler/lib/profiler_session.cc:159] Profiler session tear down.
2021-07-26 08:24:19.321288: I tensorflow/core/profiler/rpc/client/save_profile.cc:137] Creating directory: logs/20210726-082410/train/plugins/profile/2021_07_26_08_24_19
2021-07-26 08:24:19.352372: I tensorflow/core/profiler/rpc/client/save_profile.cc:143] Dumped gzipped tool data for trace.json.gz to logs/20210726-082410/train/plugins/profile/2021_07_26_08_24_19/BlueDiamond.local.trace.json.gz
2021-07-26 08:24:19.389321: I tensorflow/core/profiler/rpc/client/save_profile.cc:137] Creating directory: logs/20210726-082410/train/plugins/profile/2021_07_26_08_24_19
2021-07-26 08:24:19.389770: I tensorflow/core/profiler/rpc/client/save_profile.cc:143] Dumped gzipped tool data for memory_profile.json.gz to logs/20210726-082410/train/plugins/profile/2021_07_26_08_24_19/BlueDiamond.local.memory_profile.json.gz
2021-07-26 08:24:19.394165: I tensorflow/core/profiler/rpc/client/capture_profile.cc:251] Creating directory: logs/20210726-082410/train/plugins/profile/2021_07_26_08_24_19Dumped tool data for xplane.pb to logs/20210726-082410/train/plugins/profile/2021_07_26_08_24_19/BlueDiamond.local.xplane.pb
Dumped tool data for overview_page.pb to logs/20210726-082410/train/plugins/profile/2021_07_26_08_24_19/BlueDiamond.local.overview_page.pb
Dumped tool data for input_pipeline.pb to logs/20210726-082410/train/plugins/profile/2021_07_26_08_24_19/BlueDiamond.local.input_pipeline.pb
Dumped tool data for tensorflow_stats.pb to logs/20210726-082410/train/plugins/profile/2021_07_26_08_24_19/BlueDiamond.local.tensorflow_stats.pb
Dumped tool data for kernel_stats.pb to logs/20210726-082410/train/plugins/profile/2021_07_26_08_24_19/BlueDiamond.local.kernel_stats.pb

469/469 [==============================] - 5s 10ms/step - loss: 0.1616 - accuracy: 0.9535 - val_loss: 0.1354 - val_accuracy: 0.9601
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the values for the `profile_batch` argument in the [TensorBoard callback](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/TensorBoard)? As written, it should profile batches 500-520. If not enough batches are run, no profile will be collected.

Comment: I tried setting profile_batch = ‘1,5’, but tensorboard’s profile tab is still empty.

Comment: Do I need to run tensorboard from Chrome?  Eg tensorboard issue #2824?

Comment: Could you provide a link for the issue you referenced?

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/2874

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57835326/tensorboard-is-not-showing-any-information-in-profile-tab